# How does Symfony2 detect where to load templates from?

Tags: symfony, twig

Where does Symfony2 detect where to load templates from: from `app/Resourses/views/` or from `Bundle/Resourses/views/`?

I need to override it to look for templates in another directory before looking into `app/Resourses/views/`.

I found: `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\CacheWarmer\TemplateFinder`

Now I just need to override it. How?

Comment: I found: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\CacheWarmer\TemplateFinder Now jast need to override. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony2 works with this workflow

1. Access route, pass control to controller, render a view (template)
2. If the view is not overridden ( `app/..../` ) then bundle template is render
3. If there's an override, then took it

So the question is: how can I override a template?

There are two different ways for override templates in symfony2

- Define a template with **same name** into `app/resources` directory. Together "same name" you have to reproduce the same structure of the bundle. So, if your template is in, i.e., `myFooBundle/views/mainTemplate.html.twig` you have to override it by creating a new one template in `app/resources/myFooBundle/views` and call it `mainTemplate.html.twig`
- You have to create a new bundle from scratch and override `getParent()` method that have to return a string containing bundle name that you want to override ( `myfooBundle` ). Now if you create a new template **in the same position** of the original, you have overwritten it. This method is not recommended since you have to override controller also.