# define custom filesystem path for twig templates

Tags: symfony, twig

I've already read [How does Symfony2 detect where to load templates from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167656/how-does-symfony2-detect-where-to-load-templates-from) and another ton of articles on the web

The question was quite similar to mine, but the answer wasn't comprehensive.

I need to override a bundle-defined template inside another custom bundle. In other words I want specify another path where symfony have to look before looking in app/Resources when loading templates.

Workflow should be something like this:

first: /src/My/Bundle/Resources/views/example.html.twig (or /src/My/Bundle/OriginalBundle/views/example.html.twig)

then: /app/Resources/OriginalBundle/views/example.html.twig

finally: /src/Original/Bundle/Resources/views/example.html.twig

The standard app/Resources -> src/Original/Bundle isn't enough.

sorry for my poor english and thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add a directory for twig templates I do this:

```
chdir(__DIR__);
$this->container->get('twig.loader')->addPath('../../../../web/templates/', $namespace = '__main__');
```

this allows me to put twig templates in a folder called 'templates' in the web folder and symfony 2.3 has no issues loading them.

Comment: What is the proper file/method where i have to put that addPath call?

Comment: I have this code in my controller before I call the the render method.

Comment: thank you. Defining a standard for our project i decided that each bundle which defines templates will have a twig extension, then put your snippet in constructor like this $this->loader->prependPath(\_\_DIR\_\_ . '/../../Resources/views'); the problem i found then was in the template syntax in render function, from Bundle:Controller:view to relative/path/from/views/folder and everything works fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the `__main__` namespace necessary in order to tell symfony to prefer this alternative path when it looks for the file? Or is this a custom namespace you made up? What happens without it? And do you have to load your templates as `@__main__/foo.html.twig`?

Answer (score 9):

There's a native feature to do exactly what you want in a nice way. Escentially you can add a twig namespace to the twig configuration in app/config.yml like this:

```
twig:
    # ...
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/acme/foo-bar/templates": foo_bar
```

This creates an alias to the folder `vendor/acme/foo-bar/templates` and then you can use it to render your templates either from the controllers:

```
return $this->render(
    '@foo_bar/template.html.twig',
    $data
);
```

or from other twig templates

```
{% include '@foo_bar/template.html.twig' %}
```

Source: official cookbook http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Comment: Thanks a ton ! This is best solution if find for doing it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The class responsible for loading twig templates is stored at the service id `twig.loader`, which by default is an instance of `Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader`, and the class for *locating* templates is stored at the service id `templating.locator` and by default is an instance of the class `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator` (which itself is injected as the first parameter to `twig.loader`)

So, in theory, all you would need to do is write your own class that implements `Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocatorInterface` (or extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator`) and then inform the configuration to use your class (which I was going to look up how to do this for you, but Symfony's websites are down right now)

Comment: If possible, i don't want to override symfony standard FileLocator which accepts an array of paths in the constructor. I suppose it allows you to define custom paths. I would like to know where I can add path and the structure where I put twig templates then. I think this should be a cleaner solution than override FileLocator