# Different Twig and Templates Location in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In Symfony by default, templates can live in two different locations:

1. app/Resources/views/
2. path/to/bundle/Resources/views/

How can you render Templates also from other Locations?

1. For Example I want my Application Themes be in the web/Themes folder:

web/Layouts/layout.twig.html
web/Layouts/layout.less
...

2. Or just store Templates in a folder in base path:

web/
app/
Themes/
...

Comment: maybe this will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050384/define-custom-filesystem-path-for-twig-templates

Answer (score 0):

While you can do that as decribed in [define custom filesystem path for twig templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050384/define-custom-filesystem-path-for-twig-templates), I would not advertise to put them in the `web` directory. Things in the `web` directory are publicy available. Raw templates, before parsing should not be publicy available.

Comment: You could .htaccess your way around that, but yeah, what he said.